# Open Port in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, port

So I'm using AWS using EC2 and I'm trying to open up a port for Postgresql. In AWS I already have it open:

```
TCP
Port (Service)      Source                  Action
0 - 65535           sg-92aadda2 (default)   Delete
22 (SSH)            0.0.0.0/0               Delete
80 (HTTP)           0.0.0.0/0               Delete
5432                0.0.0.0/0               Delete
```

When I do netstat it looks as though the port is listening:

```
# netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

When I do a localhost nmap I get the following:

```
 Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
 Host is up (0.000010s latency).
 Not shown: 997 closed ports
 PORT      STATE SERVICE
 22/tcp    open  ssh
 80/tcp    open  http
 5432/tcp  open  postgresql
```

And here's where the fun begins. When I do an nmap from an alternative host I get the following:

```
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp    open   ssh
80/tcp    open   http
5432/tcp  closed postgresql
```

I also looked at my iptables to see if I was missing something, but the iptables look empty (which should mean they aren't really doing much)

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Am I missing something cause I can't seem to figure out how to access the ip. Whenever I try I get the following error:

```
Is the server running on host "xx.xx.xx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How do I make it so that I can open up the port so that external servers have access to it? Thanks in advance =) Lemme know if you need any additional data.

**EDIT**: As asked below, I tested telnetting, and I was able to telnet into the localhost, but when attempting from the outside I get:

```
$ telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 5432
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Also, I double checked and I was properly able to telnet into ssh:

```
$ telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 22
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
```

Comment: you're missing an actual question, so it's not entirely clear what you want us to answer.  Additionally, "Whenever I try I get the following error:" what are you trying that gives you that error?  Have you tried to telnet into the server?  Also, there's not much in your iptables, but if you have a default deny enabled then nothing is getting to that box EXCEPT what is specified to be allowed in your iptables

Comment: @RussellUhl Sorry, I thought I had asked it, but apparently not. I've added the question at the end. I have not tried telnetting into the server. I'll try that now.

Comment: no worries.  I edited my comment above to include something on your iptables.  Make sure you check that as well

Comment: I added the telnet data above. I'm not seeing a 'deny' anywhere in the iptables. From what I understand fail2ban doesn't actually deny anything (except when hitting the server quickly and consecutively) What line implies a deny?

Comment: I'm not familiar with iptables or fail2ban.  I use the ufw frontend.  I just know that in ufw you can set a default deny that doesnt appear to show in the iptables (unless i missed it).  I'm not sure where it would be, if it even exists.  my unspoken (sorry) point was that you should explicitly allow traffic on your port; in this case, 12345

Comment: (after reading the telnet update) yea that's almost certainly a firewall issue.  It can find the server (as evidenced by ssh success), but since there's no line in iptables to specifically allow your port, i'm gonna guess your firewall is blocking the connection

Comment: I tried opening up the port to no avail =/ I'm gonna update the code above to show my latest details. I'll also reveal the port I'm using as apparently it's a standard port anyway so it was pointless for me to hide it

Comment: @RussellUhl I updated the iptables (as shown above) to explicitely allow open connections for the port and it's still showing it as closed when I nmap it.

Comment: You said this works if you telnet from localhost into 5432?  Did you try remote telnet again?  According to nmap info, "closed" simply means that no application is actively listening for a connection, but the port is open.  While this would imply that you did not, in fact, need to make your firewall wide open (which you should lock down again), it also suggests that your server program isn't running.  Is that still up as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried both local and external telnetting and the responses are the same as above. So I'm still not able to telnet externally and I'm able to telnet locally.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at a loss, sorry.  Make sure you close your firewall back up to where it was before until you find a solution

Comment: @RussellUhl Thanks for all the help though =) I've removed the firewall fix for now until someone has a secondary solution =D

Comment: This commands shows that postgres only listens on the loopback device 127.0.0.1: "# netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN " Most likely you need to alter the postgres configuration so it listens on your network devices with outgoing connectivity as well.

Comment: @TeTeT Where is that param in the postgres configs? I wasn't able to find any outbound configuration...

Comment: @TeTeT nvm, looks like I found the config file that solved it. Thanks! If you want add it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Aram looks like we were at the same speed with the comment above :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Edit `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf` and set the `listen_addresses` to your outgoing interface or all. Restart postgresql: `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Comment: This was also helping for me: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Comment: Just a comment for anyone doing this: the `listen_addresses` IP address parameter is the one that posgresql is listening **from** (the INPUT destination in `iptables` syntax), not the IP that it is listening **to** (the INPUT source).

Answer (score 56):

It works for me the last method (thks Julio):

**Edit:** postgresql.conf

`sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`

**Enable or add:**

`listen_addresses = '*'`

**Restart the database engine:**

`sudo service postgresql restart`

---

Besides, you can check the file: **pg_hba.conf**

`sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`

And add your network or host address:

`host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5`

Answer (score 16):

If you have edited **postgresql.conf** and  **main/pg_hba.conf** and still having a problem, please try

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

to unblock psql port

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using docker to connect to the host's postgresql you have to use the host's ip which you can obtain by running `ip addr show docker0` hope it helps someone.